# Prototype with this keyword is not giving the expected result

Tags: javascript, prototype

In javascript, why this?
And for the hell of me, I can't find anything explaining it

Say

```
var ATest = function(atom, electron)
{
    this.atom = atom;
    this.electron = electron;
}
ATest.prototype.atom = 'emptyAtomA';
ATest.prototype.electron = 1;
```

I come from C# and this prototype thing is like default constructor values for javascript objects

so, i try this in Chrome console:

```
var ATestVariable = new ATest();
ATestVariable.atom
//Result->undefined
ATestVariable.electron
//Result->undefined
```

And this is strange for me, so I try in the global context (don't know, maybe using this has produced some weird assignemnt...)

```
this.atom
//Result->undefined
this.electron
//Result->undefined
window.atom
//Result->undefined
```

Nothing here too.

Now, if I try

```
var BTest = function(Atom, Electron)
{
    atomB = Atom;
    electronB = Electron;
}
BTest.prototype.atom = 'emptyAtomB';
BTest.prototype.electron = 12;
```

And then I do

```
var BTestVariable = new BTest();
BTestVariable.atom
//Result->"emptyAtomB"
BTestVariable.electron
//Result -> 12
```

This is what I get and what I would expect in both cases.

What is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do

```
var ATest = function(atom, electron)
{
    this.atom = atom;
    this.electron = electron;
}
ATest.prototype.atom = 'emptyAtomA';
ATest.prototype.electron = 1;
```

The first and second parameters passed to the constructor will be assigned to properties of the instance (`this`) *no matter what*. If you do not pass any parameters, then the values of the standalone variables `atom` and `electron` will be `undefined`, so the instance ends up having *own properties* `atom` and `electron` whose values are `undefined`.

The instance still has an *internal prototype* object, and that internal prototype has property values `emptyAtomB` and `12`, but because the instance has *own properties* with the same name, they overshadow the properties on the internal prototype.

```js
var ATest = function(atom, electron)
{
    this.atom = atom;
    this.electron = electron;
}
ATest.prototype.atom = 'emptyAtomA';
ATest.prototype.electron = 1;

var ATestVariable = new ATest();

console.log(ATestVariable.atom);
console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(ATestVariable).atom);
```

It sounds like you may be wanting to check to see if the arguments are defined first:

```
var ATest = function(atom, electron)
{
    if (atom !== undefined) {
        this.atom = atom;
    }
    if (electron !== undefined) {
        this.electron = electron;
    }
}
```

When you do

```
var BTest = function(Atom, Electron)
{
    atomB = Atom;
    electronB = Electron;
}
```

you're assigning the parameters to *global variables* `atomB` and `electronB`. This is not desirable, and will throw an error in strict mode.

Of course, it would be best to simply always pass all expected arguments to the constructor every time, if that's what your script expects:

```
var ATest = function(...args)
{
    if (args.length !== 2) {
        throw new Error('Two arguments required: atom and electron');
    }
    const [atom, electron] = args;
    this.atom = atom;
    this.electron = electron;
}
```

Comment: I Also tried
var testProto = function(){}
testproto.prototype.var1 = 'aaa'

Which works in a tutorial video, but throws undefined error in my Chrome console, what about this case?

Video is https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NhYMlbKgQzU minute 10:51

Comment: I guess that code is theoretically legal, but it's *really really weird*. Generally you'd want to have a static prototype object set up in advance, one which never gets mutated. A constructor should almost always only mutate its instance (the `this`). A constructor should not have a side effect of mutating the internal prototype, in almost all cases. If the `aaa` is meant to be instance data, it should be put on the instance; `this.var1 = 'aaa'`

Comment: `var testProto = function(){} testproto.prototype.var1 = 'aaa'` ... you do realise `testProto` and `testproto` are completely unrelated things, right?

Comment: @LiquidCore See above comment, make sure to use the same capitalization

Answer (score 0):

You're not passing any parameter to constructor when you're calling `new ATest`, so the value assigned to `this.atom` and `this.electron` turns out to be undefined

```js
var ATest = function(atom, electron)
{
    this.atom = atom;
    this.electron = electron;
}

// when values not passed to constructor
var ATestVariable = new ATest();
console.log(ATestVariable)


// when values passed to constructor
var BTestVariable = new ATest(1, 'some value');
console.log(BTestVariable)
```

Not let's talk about values added to `prototype`, the values are are `ATest` internal prototype so you need to get access values using that

```js
var ATest = function(atom, electron)
{
    this.atom = atom;
    this.electron = electron;
}
ATest.prototype.atom = 'emptyAtomA';
ATest.prototype.electron = 1;

let a = new ATest()

console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(a).atom)
console.log(a.__proto__.atom)
```